# How to index file names (and other file metadata) in nutch?

Tags: java, nutch

It seems like nutch indexes only (some) parse results. It runs the indexing filters which  detremine what is indexed.

These indexing filters get a Parse result as a parameter.

How can I achieve file names and other file metadata like owner being indexed?

Of course I need to add an indexing filter, but to do I also have to add a parser for parsing all filetypes and getting their metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details (file names, owner) will already be handled by code but i think that you need to do slight modification to parsers to store those details